# Primes of the form $4n^2-4n–1$

Tags: probability, prime-numbers

I noticed for the polynomial $4n^2-4n–1$ it produced 42 primes when testing from n=2 to 100 (results below, primes in bold).

**7**, **23**, **47**, **79**, 119, **167**, **223**, 287, **359**, **439**, 527, 623, **727**, **839**, 959, **1087**, **1223**, **1367**, 1519, 1679, **1847**, 2023, **2207**, **2399**, 2599, 2807, **3023**, 3247, 3479, **3719**, **3967**, 4223, 4487, **4759**, **5039**, 5327, **5623**, **5927**, 6239, 6559, 6887, 7223, 7567, **7919**, 8279, **8647**, 9023, 9407, 9799, 10199, **10607**, 11023, **11447**, 11879, 12319, 12767, 13223, **13687**, **14159**, **14639**, 15127, 15623, **16127**, 16639, **17159**, 17687, **18223**, 18767, **19319**, 19879, 20447, **21023**, 21607, 22199, 22799, 23407, **24023**, 24647, 25279, **25919**, 26567, 27223, 27887, **28559**, 29239, **29927**, 30623, **31327**, 32039, 32759, **33487**, 34223, 34967, 35719, **36479**, 37247, 38023, 38807, 39599

Does this polynomial have a higher chance of producing primes than random chance?

Comment: In what ways is the random chance limited? Is it limited to random positive odd numbers?

Comment: It is very likely that there are infinite primes of the form $m^2-2$, but unluckily the existence of infinite primes of the (similar) form $m^2+1$ is still an unproved conjecture, and any couple of irreducible quadratic polynomials producing some primes has asymptotically the same probability of producing primes for large inputs.

Answer (score 1):

It is known that some quadratic functions generate disproportionately many primes, at least initially. This manifests visually as diagonals in the [Ulam spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral).

You seem to have stumbled upon one of these. For a more famous example, take $n^2-n+41$, which gives primes for all $0\leq n\leq 40$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** The chance of hitting a prime by random chance should be close to the prime density function which can be approximated as the derivative (with respect to $N$) of
$$\Pi (N) = \frac{N}{\log(N)}$$
Which is proven in the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).

Comment: So because the highest result was 39599, rounding to 40000 gives an estimate of 3775 primes using the prime density function, or about 9% of the numbers up to 40000. Since 42 out of the 99 numbers resulting from $4n^2−4n–1$, or about 42% were prime, does this mean it has almost 5X the chance of hitting primes than random chance?

Comment: Yes it is one estimate, but the distribution is not uniform so it is not the best approximation we could make. But it is still quite likely that it is a lot better than random chance yes.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you choose a random integer $x$. Then the probability that $x$ is prime is of course $1/$$\log(x)$ while the probability for $4x^2-4x-1$ is $1$/$\log(2x)$, roughly twice as much as $x$. So it is estimated that for $x$, there is one integer $k$ in the range $x, x+\log(2x)$ which $4k^2-4k-1$ is prime for. Compare this with finding a prime the size of $x$ where it is expected there is one prime in the range $x, x+\log(x)$. Again this is basic, and least probability, adding in factors such that each prime factor of $4k^2-4k-1$ is congruent to $1$ or $7 \pmod 8$, the probability may increase.